# Combine 2 tables in 1 class using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, associations, linq-to-objects

I have 2 classes:

```
[Table(Name = "_Reference2")]
public class Customer
{
    [Column(Name = "_IDRRef")]
    public Binary CustomerRef { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "_Description")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table(Name = "_AccumReg2210")]
public class Payment
{
    [Column(Name="_Period")]
    public DateTime Period { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "_Fld2211RRef")]
    public Binary Customer { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "_Fld5051RRef")]
    public decimal Sum { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any opportunity to combine this classes in 1 class? Usually, I need to write query witn **JOIN** (ON Customer.CustomerRef = Payment.Customer) to this classes. It will be better to implement complex class, connected to both tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var results = from c in Customers
              from p in Payments
              where p.Customer == c.CustomerRef
              select new ComplexObject() {
                 Name = c.Name,
                 ...
              };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to join explicitly the two tables using Linq, you could create a View in your database and generate a model with it (using LinqToSQL or Entities Framework) ?

Comment: Database cannot be changed :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applies to your needed solution, but have you considered a simple CustomerPaymentViewModel class?

```
public class CustomerPaymentViewModel
{
    public Customer { get; set; }
    public Payment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I dont know, how to implement association between my classes in your example; and how will look a LINQ query to such new class. The main quest is to leave JOIN behind the scenes.